# Where is this sql trigger contain syntax error?

Tags: mysql

Spent about one hour to understand. 
Where is this sql trigger contain syntax error?

```
CREATE
TRIGGER playlis_trubric_count_on_playlist_shared_update
AFTER UPDATE ON playlist_playlist
  FOR EACH ROW
    IF (NEW.shared != OLD.shared) AND (NEW.shared = 1) THEN
        UPDATE etv.playlist_playlistrubric 
            SET count = playlist_playlistrubric.count + 1
        WHERE etv.playlist_playlistrubric.id = NEW.rubric_id;
    ELSEIF (NEW.shared != OLD.shared) AND (NEW.shared = 0) THEN
        UPDATE etv.playlist_playlistrubric
            SET count = playlist_playlistrubric.count - 1
        WHERE etv.playlist_playlistrubric.id = NEW.rubric_id
    END IF;
```

ERROR SAYS:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ELSEIF (NEW.shared != OLD.shared) AND (NEW.shared = 0) THEN
>           UPDATE etv.p' at line 1

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> **By using the `BEGIN ... END` construct, you can define a trigger that
>   executes multiple statements.** Within the `BEGIN` block, you also can use
>   other syntax that is permitted within stored routines such as
>   conditionals and loops. **However, just as for stored routines, if you
>   use the *mysql* program to define a trigger that executes multiple
>   statements, it is necessary to redefine the *mysql* statement delimiter
>   so that you can use the ; statement delimiter within the trigger
>   definition.** The following example illustrates these points. It defines
>   an `UPDATE` trigger that checks the new value to be used for updating
>   each row, and modifies the value to be within the range from 0 to 100.
>   This must be a `BEFORE` trigger because the value needs to be checked
>   before it is used to update the row:
>
> ```
> mysql> delimiter //
> mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
>     -> FOR EACH ROW
>     -> BEGIN
>     ->     IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
>     ->         SET NEW.amount = 0;
>     ->     ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
>     ->         SET NEW.amount = 100;
>     ->     END IF;
>     -> END;//
> mysql> delimiter ;
> ```

You're missing `BEGIN` and `END` and you're also going to need the delimiter trick, because at present your trigger definition ends at the first `NEW.rubric_id` (which is why the parse error occurs just after that point).